# Maintain the path in installable UnixAPI

Tags: command-line, python, path

I am developing an API in Unix environment for virtual machines. Most of the modules are developed in python. I have few questions on this.

Inside the API I am using absolute path like '/root/virtman/manager/' . Consider running this API in any unix environment , how can I make this absolute path generic to any OS/machine. Or should I have to assume some location where the API will get installed and give that path everywhere?

I read a lot of articles but I didn't get the clear picture,so any hints/suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: If you consider making and distributing this as an installable package, you should look at using `pip` and `setup.py` for installing. From that you use tools to generate `.deb` and `.rpm` files. Al kinds of things that have little to do with the functionality you want to provide, but necessary for a smooth installation procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path is only pointing to executables you call, you should consider putting links in standard locations during install (`/usr/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin`) and have the executable find out where they were invoked from and then have them derive the path to any data files from that.

You would use the following:

```
/usr/bin/myprog    
/opt/myprog/bin/myprog
/opt/myprog/data/picture_01.img
```

have `/usr/bin/myprog` be a link to `/opt/myprog/bin/myprog` and `/opt/myprog/bin/` should not be in your `$PATH`. Setup the link by doing `sudo ln -s /opt/myprog/bin/myprog` `/usr/bin`, and have in `/opt/myprog/bin/myprog` do:

```
import sys
import os

base_dir = os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]).rsplit('/bin/', 1)[0]
```

To determine `/opt/myprog` dynamically at run-time

---

If the python API is based on some included module, make sure that module gets installed in the PYTHONPATH search path of a systems python, then you can just do `import yourapimodule` in a python executable and use it.

---

If these are data files that can be installed anywhere, consider having a configuration file that you read and that could be `~/.config/yourapimodule/config.ini`, `~/.yourapimodule/config.ini` or `~/.yourapimodule.ini`.¹ (Instead of `.ini` you could use other formats like `.json`, whatever you prefer).

¹ <sub>Shameless plug: If you are using Python's `argparse` to handle commandline arguments, then have a look at the package [`ruamel.appconfig`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.appconfig), that I wrote, it sets up the config for you and allows you to specify defaults in the config file for commandline parsing.</sub>